# What processor images to install

Tags: images, android-sdk

After downloading and installing Android Dev Studio and Android SDK, a question arises:

Which System Images should one install?

For example, one would like to write a simple android game, that should be run mostly on mobile devices (e.g. pads and smartphones). I guess in this case most many Images are not needed.

Is there a good way or routine on how to choose which System Image to install? So the system is not over-flooded with unused tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The major problem with running Android virtual devices (AVDs) is that they are usually very slow, even on fast hardware. For this reason, consider using the HAXM accelerator which will work with a x86 image

https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager

You can still keep an ARM-based emulator for when you want to make sure it works, but while developing it would probably be easier to use the x86 Android image, as most of the functionality would be the same as the ARM version.

Comment: Sorry, I need 15 reputation for it :) Vote up my question, please, so I can vote up your answer and mark it as an solution.

Comment: Accepting an answer is free, but you need reputation to vote up. Also if you accept the answer, you build reputation.